# Shell - modifying the find command output

Tags: shell

Is there anyway to print and output to a find command without listing the directory of the find in your output? meaning if I issue

```
find /home/people/name -type f -name >> /output/log/output.txt
```

the output in the log is written as:

```
/home/people/name/filename1.txt
/home/people/name/filename2.txt
/home/people/name/filename3.txt
```

what I want is the just the file name without the directory name? is that possible?

Comment: Your `find` has a syntax error since `-name` requires an argument. Are all of the files you are interested in the same folder? If so, why are you using `find`? Anyway, you can get what you're after with, `find /home/people/name -type f  -exec basename {} \; >> /output/log/output.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, as you saw, `find` prints full paths:

```
$ find /home/people/name -type f
/home/people/name/filename1.txt
/home/people/name/filename3.txt
/home/people/name/filename2.txt
```

`find`, however, does offer control over the output using `-printf`.  To get just the filename, with no path, try:

```
$ find /home/people/name -type f -printf '%f\n'
filename1.txt
filename3.txt
filename2.txt
```

`%f` tells `find` that you want the filename without the path.  `\n` tells `find` that you want a newline after each filename.

The output can, of course, be saved in a file:

```
$ find /home/people/name -type f -printf '%f\n' >output.txt
$ cat output.txt
filename1.txt
filename3.txt
filename2.txt
```